# Visual Studio 2017 Community Slow Performance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I debug my solution, vs 2017 Community is very laggy and slow it's like it has to operate something heavy in the background. Even i Disabled the Diagnostic Tools while debugging in Tools → Options → Debugging → General

Comment: In visual studio 2017 help menu you will see manage visual studio performance.  Does it show anything causing visual studio to slow down?

Comment: no .. there's nothing

Comment: Disable source control. And the visual studio speed up, Use an other tool for your source control